# How to convert character codes starting with /u using PHP

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

I cannot find a way to display/echo text with a character encoding such as \u02792.
Below is the json data :

```
{"id":"65645234","firstName":"\u0906\u0926\u093f\u0924\u094d\u092f"}
```

When i try to echo firstName on html page with utf-8 character encoding support, it displays above data as it is. I even tried to utf8_decode() as well as utf8 to unicode conversion of above data but still no luck. Please tell me how to decode above text. Also what kind of character encoding is that??

> P.S. I even tried to first `utf8_decode()` and then utf8 to unicode conversion but still no luck.

Answer (score 2):

That's the JSON way to encode Unicode characters. Just decode the JSON.

```
var_dump(json_decode('{"id":"65645234","firstName":"\u0906\u0926\u093f\u0924\u094d\u092f"}', true));

array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(8) "65645234"
  ["firstName"]=>
  string(18) "आदित्य"
}
```